# How to update the Jmeter latest version in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: testing, jmeter, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Java 1.8.0_171

I used bellow commands to install the Jmeter.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jmeter
```

But it installed 2.11 version.

Comment: Try this way    https://askubuntu.com/questions/690983/how-can-i-update-jmeter-in-ubuntu/691431#691431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download directly latest JMeter version from 
      http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi or

```
http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//jmeter/binaries/
```

and then follow [installation guide](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install):

> unzip the zip/tar file into the directory where you want JMeter to be installed